# как конвертировать код на ткинтер в exe

Tags: exe

как конвертировать код tkinter  в exe если в коде есть:
window.iconbitmap("wow.ico")

Comment: а как вы конвертируете код tkinter в exe если в коде НЕТ : `window.iconbitmap("wow.ico")` ?

Comment: всмысле, когда я конвертирую с этой строчкой выводит ошибку , а когда строчки window.iconbitmap("wow.ico") нету в коде, то конвертация без ошибок